# MATLAB - How to solve error, "Scalar index required for this type of multi-level indexing"?

Tags: matlab

I have a struct called "Trials" and a field called "peakvel" which is inside a struct called "sac1str", which is then inside Trials.

I want to extract the data inside the field "peakvel".

This is my code:

```
ed(fileidx).vel_up = [Trials(Lup & Lgoodtrials).sac1str.sac1ovr_peakvel];
```

Whenever I run this I get an error, "Scalar index required for this type of multi-level indexing."

Any ideas to get around this error?

Answer (score 0):

The chaining of non-scalar indexing (`(Lup & Lgoodtrials)`) and accesing two levels of structs is not possible. Use a temporary variable in between:

```
temp=[Trials(Lup & Lgoodtrials)].sac1str
ed(fileidx).vel_up=[temp.sac1ovr_peakvel]
```

There are three types of [subsref](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html), first two are the indexing operations for cells and arrays, third is the access to a field of a struct. When using non-scalar indices (more than one element is indexed) on a top-level, you can access only one further level of the struct. The error says you can not combine multi-level indexing (in the struct) with non scalar indices (for the array). Not allowed is:

```
Trials(Lup & Lgoodtrials).sac1str.sac1ovr_peakvel
```

But allowed is the 1-level indexing:

```
Trials(Lup & Lgoodtrials).sac1str
```

Or use of scalar idices:

```
s=2
Trials(s).sac1str.sac1ovr_peakvel
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I made the change but received this error "Dot name reference on non-scalar structure." on the line "ed(fileidx).vel_up=temp.sac1str.sac1ovr_peakvel"

Comment: sac1str is a [1x1 struct] with a field called sac1ovr_peakvel

Comment: I had the wrong rules in mind. You can combine indexing and struct subref, but not two levels of struct subref. Code should be running now.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you said? That will help me understand better what you're trying to say

Comment: Added some explanations to my answer.